# Is the Gaussian function a coercive function?

Tags: compactness, coercive

Is the Gaussian function a coercive function? If so, is it possible to use coerciveness to show that the Gaussian function has a bounded support?

Comment: what have you tried in verifying or disproving the claim?

Comment: Coercive in $\mathbb R_+$ means that $f(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to\infty$ which is not the case for the Gaussian function.